# Retrofit2 POST не передаются параметры

Tags: android, retrofit, retrofit2

```
Retrofit rt;
    rt=new Retrofit.Builder().baseUrl("http://10.0.2.2/").addConverterFactory(ScalarsConverterFactory.create()).addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create()).build();
    //ServerApi sapi=rt.create(ServerApi.class);

    Foo foo=rt.create(Foo.class);

    Call<String> msg=foo.postJson(new TPEDC("author"));

    msg.enqueue(new Callback<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<String> call, Response<String> response) {

            System.out.println(response.body().toString());
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<String> call, Throwable t) {
        System.out.println(t.toString());

        }
    });
```

Код класса хранящего данные

```
public class TPEDC {
final String author;
public TPEDC(String author){
    this.author=author;
}
}
```

Интерфейс

```
public interface Foo {
    @POST("Singleton")
    Call<String> postJson(@Body TPEDC body);
}
```

В PHP скрипте, вывожу echo $_POST['author'];
Ничего не выводится. Я совершенно не понимаю почему это происходит, поэтому ответ желательно распишите подробно. Если есть подскажите материалы по Retrofit2.

Comment: А в каком виде вы хотите получать Java-обьект на стороне сервера?

Comment: @EugeneKrivenja А как мне этот объект в JSON перевести на сервере. Какой нужно указать ключ в $_POST[] что-бы его принять?

Comment: У вас вопрос по PHP, а не по ретрофиту. Обьект придет как JSON в теле запроса на сервер.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как работает HTTP POST в Retrofit.

**Вариант 1, дефолтный.**

```
public interface Foo {
  @POST("method")
  Call<RespType> postMethod(@Body ReqType body);
}
```

В этом случае выполняется HTTP POST с телом запроса, содержащим обьект body. Просто сами данные, в виде, зависящим от типа передаваемого обьекта и подключенных конвертеров.
https://futurestud.io/tutorials/retrofit-send-objects-in-request-body

**Вариант 2, HTML form data**

```
public interface Foo {
  @FormUrlEncoded
  @POST("method")
  Call<RespType> postMethod(@Field("param_name") ReqType data);
}
```

В этом случае будет происходить тоже самое, как при передаче HTML form запросом POST.
https://futurestud.io/tutorials/retrofit-send-data-form-urlencoded

Вы же пытаетесь передавая данные первым вариантом, получать на сервере по второму варианту.

Comment: Спасибо за развернутый ответ. Сейчас у меня остался вопрос. Когда я сделал вторым вариантом, оставив остальной код прежним, на сервере ответ не приходит как бы я не старался.

Comment: Я не разбираюсь в PHP чтобы помочь вам на сервере.